# Google Apps PivotCharts not working?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the PivotCharts library that is recommended in on the apps developer site here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/notable-script-libraries - but when I try replicating the example code:

```
function createReport(){
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setWidth(700).setHeight(450).setTitle('My report');
var data =   SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AnxR7WfXrj7adFRnVEFTQ2NldGJodUtCZDF2U0hVNUE').getSheets()   [0].getDataRange().getValues();
var panel = PivotChartsLib.createColumnChart(data, 3, 4);
app.add(panel);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app);
}
```

The initial chart loads, but when you try to pivot you get an error "Type Error: can not call method "apply" of undefined"

I've tested on different computers, so I think it is an issue with the library itself.  I'm not sure how to access that code though to try and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw same error.
then i copied code from PivotCarts library,
it worked fine.

it seems pivot charts library ui need apply function,
 that should be global scope function , but PivotCharts's apply function scope is into PivotCharts object.

Comment: Thanks Keisuke, so apologies if this is a dumb question, but how do I get the code itself from the library so I can copy and use it locally?

Comment: in my way. 1. Set the break point at calling any methods of PivotCharts. 2. Run your code as debug mode. 3. Use StepIn when stop running at calling PivotCarts. maybe u can see the libraly code.

Comment: ahhh - tricky.  Yes, that does work.  Thanks - I appreciate it.  Hopefully the library itself will get fixed shortly.